# if statement not exiting properly C# and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get my 'player' to change directions with my below script

however, it is contently staying stuck in the first 2 if statements of my 'void Update()'

I am trying to use these two scripts (1. https://pastebin.com/AGLatvUD (I wrote this one) and 2. https://pastebin.com/2XA3w04w)

I am attempting to use CharacterController2D to move my player with specified points and actions

Don't know if this is the right place to ask but I figured I'd try!!

```
 void Update() // not sure if should have more in 'FixedUpdate' or others (maybe?)
    {

        if (isRight && transform.position.x > currentPoint.position.x) // flipping the character -- I'm pretty sure I can use TestCharacterController2D to do this for me, this is comparing the player's 'transform' 
        {
            moveSpeed = -0.25f; // tells controller to head in the left direction
            isRight = false;   // no longer facing right 
        }
        if (!isRight && transform.position.x < currentPoint.position.x) // reverse of above
        {
            moveSpeed = -0.25f; // tells controller to head in the right direction
            isRight = true; // no longer facing left
        }

        if (transform.position == currentPoint.position) // checks to see if player is at 'currentPoint' 
        {
            pause = true; // starts the pause sequenece


            if (pause) // when the movement is pause do the the following
            {
                animator.SetFloat("Speed", 0); // player stops moving -- works!

                if (maxPause <= 100) // checks to see if still paused
                {

                    Debug.Log(maxPause);
                    maxPause--; // reduce pause amount (working way out of loop)

                    if (maxPause < 0) // found 'maxPause' was going to far below zero
                        maxPause = 0;
                }

                if (maxPause == 0) // when 'maxPause' timer has finished
                {
                    pointsSelection++; // move to netx point
                    maxPause = 100; // reset 'maxPause' timer
                    pause = false; // resume 'transform.position == currentPoint.position' process
                }

            }

            if (pointsSelection == points.Length) // makes sure 'pointsSelection' doesn't go out of bounds
                pointsSelection = 0; // start the player's movement process over again


        }
        else // not sure if requried
            Debug.Log("removed pause = false");
```

any help would be appreciated!!!

Thank you very much!!

I am an amateur (obviously :))

littlejiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing that sets the character's position *exactly* to currentPoint. There are a number of ways to solve this.  One way is to check if the character is near the currentPoint instead of exactly on it.

```
if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, currentPoint.position)  < 0.1f) {
    pause = true; // starts the pause sequenece
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked!

i Figured it was something simple like that